# In Python how to import files from directory that match certain dates newer than what is in my SQL table

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder that contains a lot of raw data .csv files for which i have a script written to import, process and then append to an SQL database table.

Each day the folder is updated with the previous day's raw csv. I am trying to write code to search the SQL database for the latest date and only import import the raw files that are new.

The Csv files always end in `DDMMYYYY_raw.csv`

so far i have:

```
#Finding the max date in the SQL server
maxdate = engine.execute("Select MAX([TableDate]) as 'Max Date' From [dbo].[SQLTable]")
for row in maxdate:
    latestdate = row[0]
    print(latestdate)

#Adding 1 day so it gets the next days data csv
date2get = latestdate + timedelta(days=1)
print(date2get)

#Working out what year, month and day to get for 
yrtoget = date2get.year
mthtoget = date2get.month
daytoget = date2get.day

#Todays Date Calclulation
timerightnow = datetime.now()
yearend = timerightnow.year
monthend = timerightnow.month
dayend = timerightnow.day

#Start and end date
start_dt = date(yrtoget, mthtoget, daytoget)
end_dt = date(yearend, monthend, dayend)

#Date Calculation
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int((date2 - date1).days) + 1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

#Create and populate list of files to get
filestoget = []
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    filestoget.append(dt.strftime("%d%m%Y") + '_raw.csv')
print(filestoget)
```

So then the filestoget gives me:

```
print(filestoget):

['06052020_raw.csv', '07052020_raw.csv']
```

Which is right.

**QUESTION: How do I now import all the CSVs that have those endings?**

This is what i currently had to import all csv files (but not for specific dates)

```
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path, '*.csv'))
for csvfile in csvfiles:
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as read_obj:
    ...#code then starts
    ...
    ...
```

Do i need to create another loop? and adjust the `csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path, '*.csv'))` line

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
endings  = ['06052020_raw.csv', '07052020_raw.csv']
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path, '*.csv'))
for csvfile in csvfiles:
    if any(csvfile.endswith(ending) for ending in endings):
        with open(csvfile, 'r') as read_obj:
        ...#code then starts
```

Comment: Thanks @Bobby Ocean. I;m basically just trying to find all files in my folder that contain `['06052020_raw.csv', '07052020_raw.csv']`. ill update the question

Comment: Thank you @Bobby Ocean. I also found a solution but just adding in an extra loop on the `filestoget`

Comment: Adding in an extra loop means that you will be searching the directory len(filestoget) * len(csvfiles), which is a lot more searching and computation than doing one loop. Be careful about doing that.

Comment: Thanks @Bobby Ocean. I didnt realise that so thats good to know. Your solution worked, thanks very much

Comment: Ya, it is really an OS issue, your asking your operating system to read through the same directory multiple times, which can be slow on very large datasets or lots of files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to get it. Simpler than i thought i just needed to add another loop in and shif all code underneath across to fall in line:

```
for files in filestoget:
    csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path, '*'+ files))
    for csvfile in csvfiles:
        # open file in read mode
        with open(csvfile, 'r') as read_obj:
        ...#code then starts
```